# How to get reference of Activity in the Adapter class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on a small app where I need to display a list of products. The products are fetched (in background) from a web api and then added to the products list and the adapter is responsible for displaying them in the view like this -

**ProductActivity** -

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new ProductAdapter(filteredProductList, R.layout.list_activity_product, ProductActivity.this);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            int addItemAtIndex = 0;
            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(addItemAtIndex);

            // scroll to top
            mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
        }
    }
});
```

As you can notice, I am passing the Activity context to adapter above. Now, as one of the properties of product object is a url (product image), I am trying to fetch it while binding the viewHolder like this (again in background) -

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    _vwHolder = viewHolder;

    ProductDetail prod = products.get(i);
    ...

    // setting image in background thread
    new setImageBitmap().execute(prod.ProductImageUrl);

}

class setImageBitmap extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{

            Log.d(TAG, "image to be fetched: " + params[0]);

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();

            InputStream inp = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inp);
            btmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(btmp, _width, _height, true);

            Log.d(TAG,"width: " + Integer.toString(btmp.getWidth()));
            Log.d(TAG,"height" + Integer.toString(btmp.getHeight()));

            _vwHolder.ProductImageUrl.setImageBitmap(btmp); // throws error

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "MalformedURLException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException");
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, when I do this I get a message (on '// throws error' line in above code) that -

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

I know that it means that I need to get the reference of activity context that called it and then run on that thread, but I am not sure how to access it from Adapter code. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was required to do was typecast the context passed to `Activity` and then move the code where I bind to `OnPostExecute` like so -

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        ((Activity)mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { // here is the change
            @Override
            public void run() {

                _vwHolder.ProductImageUrl.setImageBitmap(_btmp);
            }
        });
    }
```

Even though Sunil kind of said the same thing in the end, but he understood the problem wrong. I got this solution from another post, so posting exactly what I coded now in my code.

My app works properly now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you have found out the problem is in

```
_vwHolder.ProductImageUrl.setImageBitmap(btmp); // throws error
```

You need to put that piece of code into onPostExecute(T result) method of AsyncTask. You currently don't have it, so you need to override that method first

Comment: That is what I am doing in my ProductActivity class, but this is Adapter class, so the question was how to get the reference of activity, which I have now found an answer to.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, I think you may have misunderstood your error but I'll get to that in a moment.

You are already passing the Activity instance to the adapter contructor when you call:

```
mAdapter = new ProductAdapter(filteredProductList, R.layout.list_activity_product, ProductActivity.this);
```

But what you are probably doing is within your ProductAdapter, this is being passed on as a Context. Since ProductActivity inherits from Activity which in turn inherits from Context, you can pass your Activity instance as the Context. To get back your activity, you simply have to cast your context back to ProductActivity.

```
ProductActivity acti = (ProductActivity) context;
```

Now to discuss your error. Your getting the error as you are modifying the UI from a background thread in the line:

```
mAdapter = new ProductAdapter(filteredProductList, R.layout.list_activity_product, ProductActivity.this);
```

you are supposed to modify it only from within the UI thread. So I would suggest you to do the update simply from the onPostExecute() method of the AsyncTask class. In this case, your AsyncTask will look like

```
class setImageBitmap extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{

            Log.d(TAG, "image to be fetched: " + params[0]);

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();

            InputStream inp = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inp);
            btmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(btmp, _width, _height, true);

            Log.d(TAG,"width: " + Integer.toString(btmp.getWidth()));
            Log.d(TAG,"height" + Integer.toString(btmp.getHeight()));
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "MalformedURLException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException");
        }

        return btmp;
    }

    // This runs on the UI thread
    @Override
    protected void on PostExecuted(Bitmap btmp) {
        _vwHolder.ProductImageUrl.setImageBitmap(btmp);
    }
}
```

This should work as long as you start the AsyncTask from the UI thread.

Comment: The line you mentioned is not the problem, but rather the one in the Adapter class. The question was how to get the reference of Activity so as to invoke UI thread, which I found the answer to and will post now.

Answer (score 0):

better to use :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap btmp ) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
            }
            if (btmp !=null)  context.asyncRefresh(btmp);
        }
```

Then in adapter activity use :

```
_vwHolder.ProductImageUrl.setImageBitmap(btmp);
```

it is like this :

```
public void asyncRefresh(Bitmap btmp ) {
_vwHolder.ProductImageUrl.setImageBitmap(btmp);
}
```